# Java - возможно ли зарегистрировать аккаунт через Web-страницу?

Tags: java

Есть ли способ зарегистрировать аккаунт через Web-страницу (Например, Яндекс почту через сайт yandex.ru)?

Comment: А как по другому можно? Дополните вопрос разъяснениями.

Comment: Требуется написать приложение, которое будет создавать почтовые ящики с каким-то интервалом. В данный момент думаю, как это можно было бы реализовать в приложении. Была несколько вариантов:
1. Достать кусок кода из мобильного приложения "Яндекс.Почта", отвечающий за создание почтового ящика.
2. Использовать Web-страницу для этого.
В данный момент склоняюсь ко второму, так как пока не смог разобраться с кодом.

Comment: Не стесняйтесь дополнить собственный вопрос, есть кнопка "правка".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты подразумеваешь - чтобы за тебя регистрацию прошла программа, то да.
1) Парсишь страницу для того, чтобы получить наименование заполняемых полей.
2) Снифером  отлавливаешь запрос, который посылается на сервер при нажатии кнопки "Готово".
3) При помощи Java формируешь аналогичный запрос с необходимыми параметрами.

А теперь трудности:
1) Пройти капчу.
2) Сэмулировать все необходимые параметры в запросе, они могут быть завязаны на куки в браузере и ещё на что-нибудь  вроде идентификатора сессии.

Это стратегия, тактические  решения я здесь приводить не буду. Не хватает ни опыта, ни времени.

Comment: С капчами вопрос уже решен, так что с этим проблем не будет. Спасибо за ответ.